# Правильно ли я понимаю?

Tags: синтаксис

> Она погрузилась в мысли, которые могли бы изменить ее жизнь, если бы
>   она этого захотела.

Здесь условное (*если бы она этого захотела*) находится в подчинении у определительного предложения (*которые могли бы изменить ее жизнь*)? 
Получается аподозис — которые могли бы изменить ее жизнь, а протазис — *если бы она этого захотела*?

Answer (score 2):

Да, в русской грамматике это называется **последовательным подчинением придаточных**:придаточное определительное является главным для придаточного условного.

Answer (score 1):

К этому предложению я бы вообще не применяла эти термины. Я считала, что протазис и аподозис можно выделить в предложении, которое резко делится на 2 части.1 часть -протазис, 2-аподозис. Если бы это было СПП с одним придаточным,главное-протазис, придаточное-аподозис.То же и в периоде.

Если возможно применить термины к этому предложению, то главным для условного будет "которые могли бы изменить ее жизнь" - это протазис , а само условное "если бы она этого захотела"-аподозис.

Но в логике это будет неправильно, там обязательно деление на 2 части, а здесь явно 3.